# Input Accessory ViewController Presentation

Tags: ios, uikit

I present a an `inputAccessoryView` on as part of a `TableViewController`, though it works smoothly most of the time, I have an issue with its presentation, as it gets presented sometimes from the right side of screen or sometimes (nicer) from bottom of the screen, any idea why and how to control that?

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: Also add a video or gif